# IntelliJ won't open after update to Java 17

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I updated Java from Java 16 to Java 17 and now my editor won't work. I use IntelliJ and here is the error message:

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x4bbd0bd0) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x4bbd0bd0
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.start(StartupUtil.java:297)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:123)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)

-----
Your JRE: 17+35-LTS-2724 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Current IntelliJ IDEA version [requires Java 11 to run](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879). Remove the overrides (`idea.jdk` file/environment variables) to use the default bundled JetBrains Runtime.

Comment: How do I change my runtime without getting into the IDE because the IDE won't launch

Comment: @ShinyDev21 Please check the documentation. You likely have `idea.jdk` file residing in the [Configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory) or you have `IDEA_JDK` environment variable set. Delete this file and/or unset the environment variable to revert to the default bundled JetBrains Runtime.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP. It worked.

Comment: @CrazyCoder could you please help me regarding this. Did you found idea.jdk file? or IDEA_JDK environment variable? And also the path please of same.

Comment: @NIKHILCHAURASIA See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879 and Configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory.

Comment: I am on mac and neither of the options worked for me. i don't have the variable (checked using `echo $IDEA_JDK`) nor i have the file in the location, i have other files though. 
bundled_plugins.txt     options                 port.lock               ssl                     updatedBrokenPlugins.db

Comment: for Mac, file jdk is in /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea<version>

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, run the below command in the cmd window

> %APPDATA%\JetBrains\

you will find the IntelliJ settings files, look for the jdk file and delete it.

Comment: This work for me too , I cleaned all the settings in %APPDATA%\JetBrains\ folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows 10+, try to Run Intellij as an administrator.
I had no idea.jdk or IDEA_JDK variable to clean and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS, I removed my idea.jdk file from:

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.1/idea.jdk
```